# how can I fix the IBM DB2 Manage connections error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, db2, ibm-cloud

I recently enrolled in a SQL course on EDX and we have to create a DB using IBM cloud. Also, we have to use VScode and connect it to IBM cloud using an extension called "DB2connect".

I've installed the **MAC** (as I am using my MacBook) extension but as soon as I try to create a connection I get this error.

''' Command 'Db2: Manage Connection Profiles' resulted in an error (command 'extension.Db2ManageConnProfiles' not found)'''

Any advice on how to fix the issue? I've seen similar questions on their Github account but I haven't found any solution besides **uninstalling and installing the extension**.

Comment: Remember to reload vscode (close and restart) after you install Db2 Connect  extension. When you next restart vscode, and try creating a connection profile, you may see this message (...not found). Just wait some moments and you should see another message "Hurrah, all set".  The Manage Connection Profiles should now let you create a profile.

Comment: You can also use github to see more details about this issue. The Macbook needs to have node.js and npm and Xcode installed at specific versions. See https://github.com/ibmdb/vscode-extension/issues/15

Comment: mao, I was definitely missing Node.js. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment thread, missing dependency.

VSCODE Db2connect extension needs specific versions of npm, node.js, ( and on Mac, also  Xcode ) to be already installed.

For VSCode Db2connect issues, you can also refer to the github issueses page https://github.com/ibmdb/vscode-extension/issues

(also accessible within VSCode Db2connect > Report an issue )

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed missing Node.js